# Unusual way of parameter passing in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to implement a function in scheme that splits the given list with the function that is also given as parameter to function. To exemplify:

```
(splitby '("a" "b" "cc" "ab" "abc" "a" "b")
         (lambda (x y) (= (string-length x) (string-length y))))
```

should return `(("a" "b") ("cc "ab") ("abc") ("a" "b"))`

I'm pretty beginner in Scheme so it is really hard to understand how this 'function like' parameter works, and while implementing such a function what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, functions are objects like numbers, strings, etc. So in this case, your example is equivalent to this:

```
(define (equal-length x y)
  (= (string-length x) (string-length y)))

(splitby '("a" "b" "cc" "ab" "abc" "a" "b") equal-length)
```

The use of the function is to allow the splitting criterion to be customised. In this case, items are in the same group for as long as the given function returns a true value; otherwise a new group is created.

To get started, write a `group-equal` function, that groups equal elements together:

```
(define (group-equal lst)
  ...)
```

where, for example,

```
(group-equal '(1 2 2 3 3 3 4))
```

returns

```
((1) (2 2) (3 3 3) (4))
```

If you successfully implement that, then it's identical to your `splitby` function, except that you use the given function (`equal-length`, for example) instead of `equal?` (as `group-equal` might use).

Comment: Thank you. It was a really helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in Scheme, everything is inside parentheses. So If you want to apply the function `f` to values `x` and `y`, you write:

```
(f x y)
```

So you simply need to put `splitby` inside the first set of parens.

Secondly, functions can be passed as values into other functions, just like data is passed.
So if I have a functions:

```
(define (double x)
    (* x 2))
```

I can write another function which takes `double` as an argument:

```
(define (change_result f x)
   (f (+ 3 x)))

; (change_result double 6) returns 18
```

I can also do this the same way, if I use a lambda (anonymous) function:

```
(change_result (lambda (x) (* 3 x)) 10)
```

Comment: `s/change_result/change-result/g`. In Lisp style, identifiers use hyphens to separate words, not underscores. Reference: http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Comment: "Symbolic names are written with English words separated by hyphens.
Scheme and Common Lisp both fold the case of names in programs;
consequently, camel case is frowned upon, and not merely because it is
ugly.  Underscores are unacceptable separators except for names that
were derived directly from a foreign language without translation."

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - thanks for the info. What does "fold the case of" mean? I can't find any clues in the source.

Comment: In CL and Scheme (up to R5RS), identifiers are treated case-insensitively, so `car` is treated the same as `Car` or `CAR`. That is what case-folding refers to.